# Large arrays of objects not referencable by keys

Tags: php, arrays

We send out emails to users with the latest jobs, so we have a array of about 1800 user objects.

I use a for loop to iterate through the objects

```
$part = $this->getRequest()->getParam('part') ? : 1;
$parts = 2;

$jobagents = RAD::registry('jobagents');
$jobagentsLength = count($jobagents);   
$sliceCount = $jobagentsLength / $parts;

for ($x = 0; $x < $jobagentsLength; $x++) {
    $slice = $x + 1;
    if ($slice > ceil($sliceCount * ($part - 1)) && $slice <= ceil($sliceCount * $part)) {
        $jobagent = $jobagents[$x];
    }

}
```

The slice if is used to determain which part of the object array we use to send out (it's to heavy to send out in one chuck) - I release this could probably be done smarter - But the if passes so that isn't the issue at hand.

The issue is

```
 $jobagent = $jobagents[$x];
```

The first loop is fine, $jobagent is now a object - but after that it appears empty, and i've checked that i looped through everything by adding a echo to the loop - And i've tried print_r'ing the array, and it has 1800+ objects with keys from 0-18xx

Am i missing something with arrays of objects above a certain size and referencing them by keys? If i use a foreach the objects are fine.

**Issue resolved, array was overwritten in edge case**

Comment: Then use foreach, what's the promlem? :) And 1800 elements in array is not much really.

Comment: @Emmerman It's a question i'd like to know the answer to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really receive a list of objects (= it's a proper array), then for simplicity try:

```
$jobagents = array_slice($jobagents, $i * $sliceCount, $sliceCount);
foreach ($jobagents as $j) {
```

However I suspect that's not your actual problem source. Objects that unset themselves are somewhat uncommon.

Comment: Added some more of the code to specify the variables. I need to split up the array in the middle, but the total count might be uneven. It works with foreach, like to know why it doesn't work with for.

Comment: I would also have suspected what Emmerman said - you have sparse array keys, hencewhy a simple `for($i)` will not give correct results. But anyway, the `array_slice` splits out a block in the middle and would eschew any key consecutivity issues. -- Can't see anything else interesting within the preface code.

Comment: I figured it out, my own mistake, under a edge case the array got changed. That edge case supposedly used to be further down the array but is now at that top. It used to work fine, suddenly it stopped working - have no idea how it was caused but atleast it's resolved.

Comment: Okay. If you need to support some special handling / ordering / etc. you might benefit from wrapping your array into an ArrayObject instead, and placing any such logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, that you have really plain array

```
$jobagents = array_values(RAD::registry('jobagents'));
```